# Using Lithium-ion Battery at -40 Celsius?

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, lithium-ion, temperature

Is it possible to use a 18650 cell Lithium-ion battery down to -40 Celsius, discharge only?  There would be no charging at this temperature (I've read that causes damage to the cell).  Curious if there is a rule-of-thumb for % capacity loss at this type of extreme temperature.  My current understanding that it will be specific to the electrolyte used by different manufacturers, but is there any potential for permanent damage or a complete freeze of the electrolyte preventing current flow?  I only see charts for some batteries down to -20 Celsius.

Comment: In general, most batteries are not reliable below 0°C. If they even function at -20°C, their capacity will likely be severely reduced.  Hence data does not exist.  Note, if the application is something that can be buried, the underground temperature can be significantly warmer.

Comment: Depends on how much power you are drawing. If it is thermally insulated, the self heating might be enough to keep the battery temperature within specs.

Comment: You could look at LTO (Lithium Titanate) batteries which are rated down to this sort of temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “coolest” ad for a LiFePO4 battery that I’ve seen comes from a [Canadian](https://www.canbat.com/product/12v-100ah-cold-weather-lithium-battery/) company that states it “can be “charged down to -35’C. Yet from reading the plots on the engineering spec, it is not included. That implies you can slowly self-heat it up to -20’C, when the ESR is sufficiently low. They don’t dare say how but likely at 0.01C rate based on the rates for -20C (0.05C) and 0’C (0.1C).

This is not due to loss of Ah but due to rapid rise in ESR from which self-heating can imbalance each cell greatly if current is too high, further degrading the lifespan of the battery. If you used the battery power to self heat, you will lose most of your Ah by the time you reach -20’C , I suspect, so for now -20’C with the derated max Ah rating must be followed to avoid damage.

Although I could ask a former colleague who got the 1st Mitsubishi car which I saw in January, which performed quite well after a 30yr anniversary of Unisys closing in Winnipeg. he claimed it was the best “winter car” he ever had for city driving. Lower Motor DCR and thus more starting torque available, instant electric heat and a high power stock BOSE stereo in a very comfortable iMEV compact. The opposing need for cooling to prevent Thermal Runaway and need to insulate for cold weather must take into consideration the thermal time constant and would be a great design challenge. Cool when moving and insulate when parked.

Answer (score 1):

Li-ion batteries usually cannot provide any significant output below ~-25 to -30C where the electrolyte freezes.

They cannot be charged at low temperatures below ~0C without the risk of lithium plating on the electrodes. This not only permanently reduces the capacity of the cell but can be dangerous.

Electric vehicles will always warm the batteries before attempting to charge at low temperatures.

Although EVs are usually rated for low-temperature operation they have enough thermal mass so the batteries can keep above the minimum operaitng temperatures for a limited period.

For example, Tesla states their cars should not be kept at below -30C for more than 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

There are ads for [cells down to -50°C](https://www.grepow.com/page/low-temperature-battery.html). That said, as mentioned above, keeping the battery in a pants pocket or burying below frostline, or even in a glacier, might be more practical... and much less expensive. If it's in use on an animal radio-tracking tag, place it next to the skin.